# Why is my list empty when it goes through volley?

Tags: java, android, json, spring-boot, arraylist

> I have being trying to crack this for sometime now! I want to post
>   data from android to
>   [Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm) using [rest web
>   services](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm) that I
>   created.
>
> In [android](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm), I
>   created a private method to get all products and get them ready
>   for http post, hence the map for each item in the list:

```
private List getAllProducts() {

        ArrayList formatProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        for ( int i =0; i < ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts.size(); i++ ) {

            Item allProducts = ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts.get(i);

            Map<Object, Object> insertData = new HashMap<>();

            formatProducts.add( new SaveOrderFormat(
                    insertData.put("name", allProducts.getName() ),
                    insertData.put("manufacture", allProducts.getManufacture() ),
                    insertData.put("price", allProducts.getPrice() ),
                    insertData.put("image", allProducts.getImage() ),
                    insertData.put("count", allProducts.getQuantity() ) )
            );
        }

        return formatProducts;
    }
```

> My volleyCall method:

```
private void volleyCall(String email, int totalQuantity, double cost, String phoneNumber, String address, String closeShop,
                            String contact, String orderDate, String deliveryDate, List orderedItems ) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "http://........:8080/order/service/save/order";
        Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
        jsonParams.put("cusEmail", email);
        jsonParams.put("totalQuantity", totalQuantity);
        jsonParams.put("totalCost", cost);
        jsonParams.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        jsonParams.put("address", address);
        jsonParams.put("closeShop", closeShop);
        jsonParams.put("contact", contact);
        jsonParams.put("status", "ordered");
        jsonParams.put("orderDate", orderDate);
        jsonParams.put("deliveryDate", deliveryDate);
        jsonParams.put("orderedItems", orderedItems );

        Log.d( TAG, "Json:" + new JSONObject(jsonParams));
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // handle error
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error" + error + "\nmessage" + error.getMessage() );
                    }
                });

        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

> OnCreate method calls volley:

```
volleyCall(
        ShoppingCartController.getInstance().keepUserSession, ShoppingCartController.getInstance().totalQuantity, 
        ShoppingCartController.getInstance().totalCart, str_phoneNumber, str_address, str_close, 
        contact, dateFormat.format(orderDate),
        String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(new Date(deliverYear - 1900, deliverMonth, deliverDay))),
        getAllProducts() 
);

Log.d("*******: : : : ", getAllProducts().toString() );
```

> In my console log (android studio), I have the following statements:

```
D/Saving Order : : :: Json:{"cusEmail":null,"totalQuantity":2,"phoneNumber":"","address":"","closeShop":"","contact":"By email:::","orderedItems":[null,null],"deliveryDate":"0002-12-31","orderDate":"2018-01-30","totalCost":29.48,"status":"ordered"}

D/*******: : : :: [store.pnp.com.pnp_store.helper.SaveOrderFormat@8a88345, store.pnp.com.pnp_store.helper.SaveOrderFormat@41d1a9a]

D/Saving Order : : :: Errorcom.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                      messageorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

> My problem is that, my arrayList returns a json data of
>   "orderedItems":[null,null] on the console when posting data, which
>   then result in saving order error (End of input at character 0 of). Not so sure about the error though!

---

### How can I fix this error?

By the way, my json data should look like this when posted and retrieved:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cusEmail": "...",
        "totalQuantity": 11,
        "totalCost": 296.89,
        "phoneNumber": "844 463 9211",
        "address": "...",
        "closeShop": "...",
        "contact": "...",
        "status": "...",
        "orderDate": "2017-15-12",
        "deliveryDate": "2017-12-18",
        "orderedItems": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "...",
                "manufacture": "...",
                "price": 13.99,
                "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/...
                "count": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "...",
                "manufacture": "...",
                "price": 20.99,
                "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/...
                "count": 7
            },
            {..., ..., ...}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: why do you call getAllProducts several times?

Comment: those times are for testing, when called with volley that is when it is put into work.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what `SaveOrderFormat` is and what its constructor expects.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Map<Object, Object> insertData = new HashMap<>();

        formatProducts.add( new SaveOrderFormat(
                insertData.put("name", allProducts.getName() ),
                insertData.put("manufacture", allProducts.getManufacture() ),
                insertData.put("price", allProducts.getPrice() ),
                insertData.put("image", allProducts.getImage() ),
                insertData.put("count", allProducts.getQuantity() ) )
        );
```

You are throwing away all product data here. You add it to `insertData`, but never use `insertData`. What you add to `SaveOrderFormat` is just a bunch of `null`s.

From the javadocs about `put`:

> Returns:
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here in line

```
        jsonParams.put("orderedItems", orderedItems );
```

Your must put is Map, not List. 
Example:

```
 Map<Object, Object> insertData = new HashMap<>();

    formatProducts.add( new SaveOrderFormat(
            insertData.put("name", allProducts.getName() ),
            insertData.put("manufacture", allProducts.getManufacture() ),
            insertData.put("price", allProducts.getPrice() ),
            insertData.put("image", allProducts.getImage() ),
            insertData.put("count", allProducts.getQuantity() ) )
    );
```

And:

```
 jsonParams.put("orderedItems", insertData);
```